# In AWS is it possible to stop data from leaving a VPC but still allow access to the data once they're connected?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Say I have ec2 instances in a subnet that contains sensitive information, but I also want developers to get access to that data once they're connected to the VPC through something like a Bastion host. Can I block them from copying the data out? Disabling sftp won't solve anything and as long as they have read permission on the data they are able to copy the data locally. Is there such an approach?

Comment: How would you possibly prevent them from copy and pasting from their terminal, even if there was a theoretical way to prevent it from being transferred?

Comment: Right it seems like the approach would be to assume they can copy that data and mask or encrypt data we don't want them to have.

Comment: Or you might investigate options for remote viewing/interaction with the app/data e.g. AppStream, Workspaces, or Windows RDP where group policy has disabled copy/paste. I'm assuming these systems would not have outbound to the internet so that users could not exfiltrate data that way.

Comment: Thank you that helps a lot!

Comment: @jarmod users can still take pictures of the sensitive data either via screenshot or a camera pointed at their monitor. Still likely the best route for OP

Comment: @jordanm yes, for sure, but certain organizations also have measures to combat that, e.g. security clearance and SCIF with no electronics introduced into the environment.

Comment: Yes, I have seen rooms where the computers had no disk drives and the USB ports were disabled, and the system could only be accessed by the computers in that room. It can take a lot of work to lock-down such systems.